# accessing values from a dataframe column made of array

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have below a column3 in df which is made of array of values. I want to access each elements from column3 but I am unable to.

I tried indexing df.column3[1] but it returns all the values. I see some other SO threads which mentions applymap or unpack method but not sure if it applies here and based on example how to use them
For simplicity I am showing only 1 row. Also data is timeseries so one of the col is timestamp again for simplicity just col1 with value a

```
       column1.     column 2                column 3
Row1      a          2          [{port_no=1, status=0, ts=1624467015}, {port_no=2, 
                                status=0, ts=1624467015}]
```

Expected output - ability to query each port_no and its status - I dont mind creating independent df columns for each port_no and its associated value.

Expected output dataframe

```
       col1. col2  column 3                             col 4
Row1      a   2 [{port_no=1,status=0,ts=1624467015}] [{port_no=1,status=0,ts=1624467015}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using apply to create an unknown number of columns:

```
data = [
    ['a', 2, [{'port_no': 1, 'status': 0, 'ts': 1234}, {'port_no': 2, 'status': 0, 'ts': 2345}]],
    ['b', 3, [{'port_no': 1, 'status': 0, 'ts': 3456}, {'port_no': 2, 'status': 0, 'ts': 4567}, {'port_no': 3, 'status': 0, 'ts': 5678}]]
]
columns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df
  column1  column2                                            column3
0       a        2  [{'port_no': 1, 'status': 0, 'ts': 1234}, {'po...
1       b        3  [{'port_no': 1, 'status': 0, 'ts': 3456}, {'po...


def split_to_columns(row):
    column_3 = row['column3']
    for x in range(len(column_3)):
        row[f'column{x + 3}'] = column_3[x]
    return row


df = df.apply(lambda x: split_to_columns(x), axis=1)
df
  column1  column2                                  column3                                  column4                                  column5
0       a        2  {'port_no': 1, 'status': 0, 'ts': 1234}  {'port_no': 2, 'status': 0, 'ts': 2345}                                      NaN
1       b        3  {'port_no': 1, 'status': 0, 'ts': 3456}  {'port_no': 2, 'status': 0, 'ts': 4567}  {'port_no': 3, 'status': 0, 'ts': 5678}
```

Comment: sorry for delayed response - and thanks a lot for the help - it works !!

Answer (score 0):

Just try `explode`

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['column 3'].explode().tolist())
Out[26]: 
   port_no  status          ts
0        1       0  1624467015
1        2       0  1624467015
```

Comment: thanks for the response - I see your point with explode but it messes up larger dataframe - any way we can select elements from the array/list and create a new column out of it ?